# CMake error to build the project with Cyrillic letters

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-gui, cryengine, cmake-server

I have error with build my project.

I use last CMake version.

And CryEngine.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Crytek\CRYENGINE Launcher\Crytek\CRYENGINE_5.3\Tools\CryVersionSelector\cryrun.exe" "build" "C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE Projects\My Project\Game.cryproject"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cryselect.py", line 595, in <module>
  File "cryselect.py", line 510, in cmd_run
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0490' in position 28: character maps to <undefined>
Failed to execute script cryselect
```

Problem with endcoding:

> РЎР±РѕСЂРєР° РЅР°С‡Р°С‚Р° 03.07.2017 11:48:53.
>
> РџСЂРѕРµРєС‚ "C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ba43f.vcxproj"
>   РІ СѓР·Р»Рµ 1 (С†РµР»РµРІС‹Рµ РѕР±СЉРµРєС‚С‹ РїРѕ СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ).
>
> PrepareForBuild:
>
> РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРёРµ РєР°С‚Р°Р»РѕРіР° "cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\".
>
> РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРёРµ РєР°С‚Р°Р»РѕРіР° "C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE
>   Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\".
>
> РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРёРµ РєР°С‚Р°Р»РѕРіР°
>   "cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\cmTC_ba43f.tlog\".
>
> InitializeBuildStatus:
>
> РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅРёРµ
>   "cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\cmTC_ba43f.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild", С‚Р°Рє
>   РєР°Рє Р±С‹Р»Рѕ Р·Р°РґР°РЅРѕ "AlwaysCreate".
>
> ClCompile:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c
>   /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D
>   "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS
>   /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR
>   /Fo"cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\" /Fd"cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd
>   /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\feature_tests.cxx"
>
> РћРїС‚РёРјРёР·РёСЂСѓСЋС‰РёР№ РєРѕРјРїРёР»СЏС‚РѕСЂ Microsoft (R)
>   C/C++ РІРµСЂСЃРёРё 19.10.25019 РґР»СЏ x64
>
> (C) РљРѕСЂРїРѕСЂР°С†РёСЏ РњР°Р№РєСЂРѕСЃРѕС„С‚ (Microsoft
>   Corporation).  Р’СЃРµ РїСЂР°РІР° Р·Р°С‰РёС‰РµРЅС‹.
>
> cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /Od /Ob0 /D WIN32 /D
>   _WINDOWS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /GR
>   /Fo"cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\" /Fd"cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\vc141.pdb" /Gd
>   /TP /errorReport:queue "C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\feature_tests.cxx"
>
> feature_tests.cxx
>
> Link:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe
>   /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_ba43f.exe"
>   /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib
>   shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib
>   /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:/Users/HP/Documents/CRYENGINE
>   Projects/My
>   Project/Solutions/Game.win_x64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_ba43f.pdb"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT
>   /IMPLIB:"C:/Users/HP/Documents/CRYENGINE Projects/My
>   Project/Solutions/Game.win_x64/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/Debug/cmTC_ba43f.lib"
>   /MACHINE:X64  /machine:x64 cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\feature_tests.obj
>
> cmTC_ba43f.vcxproj -> C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_ba43f.exe
>
> FinalizeBuildStatus:
>
> Р¤Р°Р№Р» "cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\cmTC_ba43f.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild"
>   СѓРґР°Р»СЏРµС‚СЃСЏ.
>
> РћР±СЂР°С‰РµРЅРёРµ Рє
>   "cmTC_ba43f.dir\Debug\cmTC_ba43f.tlog\cmTC_ba43f.lastbuildstate".
>
> РЎР±РѕСЂРєР° РїСЂРѕРµРєС‚Р° "C:\Users\HP\Documents\CRYENGINE
>   Projects\My
>   Project\Solutions\Game.win_x64\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ba43f.vcxproj"
>   Р·Р°РІРµСЂС€РµРЅР° (С†РµР»РµРІС‹Рµ РѕР±СЉРµРєС‚С‹ РїРѕ
>   СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ).
>
> РЎР±РѕСЂРєР° СѓСЃРїРµС€РЅРѕ Р·Р°РІРµСЂС€РµРЅР°.
>
> ```
> РџСЂРµРґСѓРїСЂРµР¶РґРµРЅРёР№: 0
>
> РћС€РёР±РѕРє: 0
> ```
>
> РџСЂРѕС€Р»Рѕ РІСЂРµРјРµРЅРё 00:00:00.97

I have Russian language in Windows

Visual Studio 2017 English version

Comment: Your question title suggest that you have an issue with CMake however question content contains two snippets that don't seem to be related to each other or to CMake. I don't know what is the problem with first snippet, however the second snippet contains utf-8 output of VS2017 with Russian localization interpreted as Windows-1251. Where do you get these from?

Comment: It`s log of CMake. First its console error [this](https://answers.cryengine.com/storage/temp/744-2017-06-27-20-05-49.png) CMakeOutput

Comment: I had a similar issue: i couldn't compile my project because of some spaces in the path of installation of CryEngine and in the path of the project itself. I reinstalled CryEngine in a different path (without spaces, as C:\Cryengine\) and moved the project to another location (without spaces in the path), I tried to recompile and it worked. So if you are sure you didn't modified the code (to exclude an error in your code), change the paths and it should work (place them in a path with only normal chars, no cyrilic, no accents, spaces or similar)